# Error installing cocoapods "sudo gem install cocoapods" MacOs Catalina

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, swift5

I am trying to install `cocoapods` in my mac system but Unfortunately not able to install due to below error.

I have already used below commands.

- `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods --pre`
- `export GEM_HOME=~/.gems
  export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
  gem install cocoapods`

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you don't have access to usr/bin directory. i have been there!!

please try below command.

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

this should work. Thanks!!

Please refer [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really?newreg=068dc403fea74a3eb1e434b955924023) post more information about access rights.

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't have the commande lines tool on Xcode...

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
xcode-select --install
```

Keep us posted...

Comment: I have tried command xcode-select --install but getting this error "xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates"

Comment: Install directly from Apple Dev Center then : https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Okay doing that.

Comment: This worked. After that tried again  “sudo gem install cocoapods" and all works.

Comment: I was able to get Cocoapods installed on my M1 chipset MacBook Air with these commands and putting into the user bin folder. You all rock!! 

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, my problem was that ruby version 2.6.0 is the default version on mac os.
so i installed [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)

and set ruby to version 3.0.3
now it works

Answer (score -1):

Run the following on terminal:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

If you don't have Homebrew yet, run this:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```